# Including a TOC entry at 'wrong' place in section hierarchy

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a document structured like

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\includegraphics{a_map.jpg}

[...]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

[...]

\chapter{Maps}

\includegraphics{b_map.jpg}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Map B}
\newpage
\includegraphics{c_map.jpg}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Map C}
\end{document}
```

I would like to include a table to contents entry for map A, which is an image file located in Chapter 1. However, I would like to include the entry as a section under the "Maps" chapter-level entry in the TOC. In other words, I want a TOC that looks like

```
Chapter 1 ................ 3
    Section 1.1........... 2
    Section 1.2........... 4
Chapter 2 ................ 5
Maps ..................... 7
   Map A ................. 3
   Map B ................. 7
   Map C ................. 8
```

Are there any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Comment: There are no `\chapter` with `article`!?

Comment: You can just insert the `\addcontentsline` where you want it to appear.

Comment: @Johannes_B you're right, it was me being too fast putting the MWE together.

Comment: It is not an MWE if you didn't test it and it doesn't work. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B but if I put the `\addcontentsline` command at the start of the maps chapter then the page number will be wrong, because the map is on p3.

Comment: Hm, right. Have you thought about a `List of Maps`?

Comment: @Johannes_B I did, but I am space constrained and wanted to squeeze everything into one table if I could.

Comment: You can redefine the title of that list not to start on a new page.and to be smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\addcontentsline` is

```
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
```

so as you want to fake the page number use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Map A}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Map B}
```